# Is it possible to add a second `drupal.behaviors` to your module?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a module that uses a bit of jQuery.

But when I submit a form I want it to call an other bit of jQuery on the landing page.

So I thought adding another `Drupal.behaviors` to my module.
But this doesn't seam to work.

```
(function ($) { 
  Drupal.behaviors.popover_hide = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
     // open link in new window.
     var linky = $('clickedme').attr("href");
     alert(linky);
     alert('linky');
     // remove class from link

     // set focus on new window eventueel
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

when I already have a `Drupal.behaviors.popover` loaded. ("popover" is the name of the module)

Comment: Is this question still good enough to help other people? please close it you think it is not. ( see my answer )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this does work I just needed to clear cache...

If you have this issue:
go to `admin/config/development/performance` and press the clear cache button.

`.js` files are cached even though if you have set caching to disabled on the page I just mentioned.